# MongoSwiftSync driver. MongoCollection.insertMany(). Cast from 'any Error' to unrelated type 'MongoError.BulkWriteError' always fails

Tags: swift, mongodb, error-handling, casting

I'm in Swift 5.8, in Xcode 14.3, on macOS 13.3.1, MacBook Pro M1 Max.  Locally hosted MongoDb Community Server 6.
I have this function:

```
func fInsertSome(_ sCollection: String, documents: [some Codable]) throws {
    let zCollection = zDb.collection(sCollection.lowercased()) // returns actual collection from collection name
    let azDocuments = try documents.map { try BSONEncoder().encode($0) }
    do {
        try zCollection.insertMany(azDocuments)
    }
    catch {
        if let errorCode = (error as? MongoSwift.MongoError.BulkWriteError)?.writeFailures?.first?.code, errorCode == 11000 {
            // one of the documents has a duplicate key.  If so, switch to writing them one by one, and handle each one individually:
            for document in documents {
                do {
                    let zDocument = try BSONEncoder().encode(document)
                    try zCollection.insertOne(zDocument)
                }
                catch {
                    if let errorCode = (error as? MongoSwift.MongoError.WriteError)?.writeFailure?.code, errorCode == 11000 {
                    }
                    else {
                        print("This error occurred when trying to insertOne: ", error)
                        throw error
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("This error occurred when trying to insertMany: ", error)
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a warning on the two `if let errorCode ... errorCode == 11000` lines:
"Cast from 'any Error' to unrelated type 'MongoError.BulkWriteError' always fails"

I've read the documentation ([here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-swift-driver/docs/current/MongoSwift/Structs/MongoCollection.html)) that says these two functions throw four types of errors each (including the two I'm using: MongoError.BulkWriteError, MongoError.WriteError), but it seems I'm not casting it correctly, or something...?

I've tried a few things, including some suggestions from ChatGPT, but neither it nor I can figure it out, so far.

Can anyone here help please?

Thanks in advance!